# My hover has been deactivated after I clicked on the link

Tags: css, html

Guys I have a problem when I click on a button on my website it would work like I want it. However, the home page button when I clicked it on the first time and the background colour did changed, but when I wanted to do that again the background colour stopped changing...
So I did this piece of code at the end of my CSS and still it wouldn't work. Is there a problem with the code?

```
a:hover{ text-decoration: none; color:#45423D;}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Clicking and hovering are two different actions – the `:hover` selector does not influence how a link looks after (or during) clicking, it only changes the link's appearance when the cursor hovers over (= lingers on) an element.

Comment: You need to provide a real [MCVE], not just a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

In which browser did you test this ?

If it is Google Chrome and you use the Dev-Tools you may be in Responsive Device mode where Google Chrome acts sometimes weird.
This looks like : [image: Responsive Mode]

If so, type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. This should help in Google Chrome.

This is the code that I have tested and it works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            a:hover { color:#45423D; background-color: red; }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button><a>test</a></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there you were changing the color attribute not background color so the code by platin 21 should work .. Your code should be sth like
.   a:hover { text-decoration: None;
.      background-color: #45423D; }

Hope u understand